# Getting JSON in PHP from jQuery .ajax()

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, null

I'm having trouble getting JSON data sent from JavaScript to PHP. Here is my Javascript:

```
var noteData =  { 
    nData: {
        "postID": $postID,
        "commentPar": $commentPar,
        "commentValue": $commentValue
    } 
}
var sendData = JSON.stringify(noteData);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: templateUrl+"/addnote.php",
    data: sendData,
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(data) { 
        alert(data);
        console.log(sendData);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
        console.log(noteData);
        console.log(sendData);
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Here is how I just test if the data is even being passed to PHP, it always returns back **null**.

```
<?php
  $nData = json_decode($_POST['nData']);
  echo json_encode($nData);
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Pekka웃 explain that please?

Comment: I somehow misread that you decode it at first (even though I thought I double-checked), sorry. Disregard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending the data as raw JSON to PHP, not as POST parameter.

There are two alternatives. The first one leaves your PHP intact:

```
var noteData =  { 
    nData: {
        "postID": $postID,
        "commentPar": $commentPar,
        "commentValue": $commentValue
    } 
}
var sendData = JSON.stringify(noteData);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: templateUrl+"/addnote.php",
    data: {
        nData: sendData
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(data) { 
        alert(data);
        console.log(sendData);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
        console.log(noteData);
        console.log(sendData);
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

The second one modifies the PHP side alone. You need to read the input stream directly to obtain the raw data.

```
<?php
$nData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
echo json_encode($nData);
```

This one might be slightly different depending on the server configuration. See the documentation on the [input stream wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

Comment: The second solution worked, the first one still gave me null.  I was wondering which one is considered best practice, or more secure?

Comment: Security is equivalent on both sides. As for the best practice, I would probably go with the second one if you need to send complex data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Tell your post request that you are sending json object
contentType: "application/json"